# Grep only for content between tags

Tags: grep, regular-expression, html

I have an html-type of file that somewhere includes a tag as follows:

```
<Currentnumber>0.3.5</Currentnumber>
```

How do I catch in a variable the value `0.3.5` and **only** this?

I have come as far as grepping the line as follows:

```
grep -E "<Currentnumber>.*</Currentnumber>$" myfile
```

I would appreciate if for educational purposes any answer also provided an explanation of the `grep` parameters used.

Pls note that the line starts with some empty spaces (or tabs), this is why the following will not work

```
grep -E "^<Currentnumber>.*</Currentnumber>$" myfile
```

Comment: Obligatory link to [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4957508)

Comment: HTML and XML are _not_ regular languages and one should _not_ be attempting to parse them with regular expressions.

Comment: @DopeGhoti so what is the best/recommended way of going about this?

Comment: HTML or XML parsers exist.  Use the right tool for the right job.  Such as `xmllint --xpath`.

Answer (score 6):

Never parse html with regex ! That's the most common mistake on stackexchange sites.

Better use a XML/HTML parser like [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint), [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) or [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project

Examples :

```
xmllint --xpath '//Currentnumber/text()' file.html
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Currentnumber/text()' file.html
saxon-lint --xpath --html '//Currentnumber/text()' file.html
```

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4957508)

Comment: I am on an immutable container with no option of installing something and these tools are not available.

Comment: Tell your sysOp or devOps to add them in the container

Comment: @GillesQuenot - "Go tell your devops to add xmllint to the container" is delusional of how production works, and uncalled-for rudeness.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed and regex

```
sed -e 's/<Currentnumber>\(.*\)<\/Currentnumber>/\1/' file.html
```

Comment: Upvoted, because someone downvoted it for wrong reasons. I like my approach better, but this is also clean.

Comment: No, this is not clean

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this helps the next person:

```
$ echo '<Currentnumber>0.3.5</Currentnumber>' | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f1
0.3.5
```

**About this answer:**

- Your string/haystack is "known", yeah? So tricks like this are fair.
- I'll point out the flaw: If someone changes the markup, this solution may need to be updated. Fine. (That is still no reason to resort to non-performant and less maintainable regex.. not for "this")
- (Maybe make a test or sanity check that you always get a build number back, so such a change is noticed quickly)
- No special tool needed... even if you have a minimal shell, `cut` will be there. (The answer to "ask devops to install a linter inside the container" is going to be a complete non-starter)